# Refactoring callable for Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I'm upgrading from Django 1.6 to 1.7, and I'm coming across a tricky issue. I've got a model field for a profile picture like this:

```
profile_image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to=get_user_uploadto_callable('photos'), null=True,
    verbose_name=_('photo'), blank=True)
```

...and my get_user_uploadto_callable looks like this:

```
def get_user_uploadto_callable(subdir):
    '''Return a callable that returns a custom filepath/filename
    for an uploaded file as per `get_user_upload_path`.

    '''

    def _callable(instance, filename):
        return get_user_upload_path(instance, subdir, filename)

    return _callable
```

However this is no longer acceptable to Django, and causes this error when I try to make migrations:

```
ValueError: Could not find function _callable in myproj.core.util.
Please note that due to Python 2 limitations, you cannot serialize unbound method functions (e.g. a method declared
and used in the same class body). Please move the function into the main module body to use migrations.
For more information, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#serializing-values
```

So I need to move this `_callable` outside the method (probably rename it to something like `user_uploadto_callable`) but still have access to the `subdir` argument being passed in. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to use the result of `get_user_uploadto_callable` as the callable in Python 2, but you can define a function which does the same thing.

```
def profile_image_upload_to():
    # you can reduce this to one line if you prefer, I used
    # two to make it clearer how it works
    callable = get_user_uploadto_callable('photos')
    return callable()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=profile_image_upload_to, null=True,
        verbose_name=_('photo'), blank=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same error: it looks like the issue is with the `_callable` function being inside another function definition.

Comment: Thanks, that version works! Ideally though it would be good to be able to add the argument in the field definition, but I'm aware this may not be possible in Python 2 with Django's migration system. I'll wait a bit to accept this answer in case something magic comes along...